# Windows Form only refreshes(rerenders) button.visible when any other button is pressed.[c#]

Tags: c#, forms, button, refresh, program-entry-point

I have a main form called "Main" which dynamically resizes itself depending on what buttons are enabled. Inside of Main I also have a function called Updater. Updater reloads all the information from a file into memory, does a tiny bit of processing, and then 'should' refresh the window. This is the refreshing part:

```
Application.DoEvents();
this.Refresh();
```

Then I have another form that is a configuration page. Simply opens up the same data file, lets the user change things, and saves it back. Which then closes itself and runs Updater which should simply refresh the Main form with the new information. Here is the calling code:

```
Main main = new Main(); 
main.UpdaterCaller();
```

Now understand the new information is enabling and disabling buttons and positioning them. I know this all works as when I ran it, i put a snippet of console code that lets me know it has run through it. But when I close the configuration window, the console displays the message that is written within Updater(), but it doesn't show the changes on Main. Only when I click any other message does is instantly refresh with teh new buttons.

Sorry if I wasn't specific enough or didn't use correct termonology. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have not posted enough code for us to be of any real help to you.

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is that the configuration page is creating a new instance of Main and updating that.  This instance is actually invisible since it has never been shown.

I'd simply display the configuration page via ShowDialog() and then have Main update itself once it's closed:

```
// ... this code is running in form Main ...
frmConfiguration config = new frmConfiguration();
config.ShowDialog(); // code here STOPS until "config" is closed
this.UpdaterCaller();
```